# Пробовал или пробывал?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: "он проб**о**вал себя в..." или "проб**ы**вал"?

Answer (score 3):

В *современном* русском языке используется глагол [**про́бовать**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C):
**1.** *кого-что*. Испытывать, проверять что-либо. *Пробовать мотор. Пробовать механизм. Пробовать голос. Пробовать свои силы, возможности. **Пробовать себя.** Пробовать артиста на какую-либо роль.*

Да и на роль Смердякова **пробовал себя** Василий Васильевич и, чего греха таить, порой настолько талантливо входил в образ, что трудно сказать, роль это или органика. [Л. А. Левицкий. Дневник (1991)]

Вознесенский **пробовал себя** в качестве чтеца-декламатора, исполнив стихотворение Пастернака «Осень» (в честь присутствующей в зале родственницы классика)... [Юнна Чупринина. Заложник Политехнического // «Общая газета», 1995]

Глагол [**пробыва́ть**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/338146) считается устаревшим и имеет такое значение:
пробыть где, пребывать, проживать, находиться, жить. Он пробывает теперь в Москве, а лето пробывает в деревне. Он пробыл у меня с месяц. Я, думаю, пробуду в Москве до весны (В. И. Даль. **1863—1866**).

А. Ф. Писемский. Люди сороковых годов (**1869**):

> — Но где же ты **пробывал** все время до острога? — продолжал спрашивать его Вихров.
> — Да где, ваше высокоблагородие, **пробывал**?.. Где день, где ночь!

Правильно: *проб**о**вал себя.*
Дополнительно: [Правильное правописание: “пробовать” или “пробывать”](https://russkiypro.ru/pravilnoe-pravopisanie-probovat-ili-probyvat/#:%7E:text=%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%20%E2%80%9C%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%E2%80%9D,%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%E2%80%9D.)

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: ***он пробовал (= испытывал) себя в...***

1. Из словаря:

**ПРОБОВАТЬ**,  нсв. (св. попробовать). 1. кого-что. **Испытывать, проверять что-л.** П. мотор. П. механизм. П. голос. П. свои силы, возможности. П. себя. П. артиста на какую-л. роль. 2. что. Есть или пить для пробы, чтобы определить вкус, готовность чего-л. П. салат. П. соус. П. вино. П. на вкус. 3. с инф. Пытаться, стараться что-л. сделать. П. писать стихи. П. работать по ночам. П. починить магнитофон. Несколько раз пробовал бегать по утрам.

2. При образовании формы прошедшего времени суффикс ТЬ заменяется суффиксом Л:
   ***проб/ова/ть — проб/ова/л.***
3. **Выбор суффикса ОВА** в глаголе "пробовать" определяется наличием чередования на У/Ю при спряжении: проб/ова/ть — проб/у/ю.

**Примечание.** К чему дается вся остальная информация в первом ответе, я вообще не понимаю.